# Insert query with case or if-else logic possible?

Tags: sql, insert

I want to insert values present in SELECT Statement below into table @tab3.
But I want to apply some sort of if-else or case logic to check like this one:

```
if (ABCList,1) = 'DOB' Then insert it into Dob1 else NULL
if (ABCList,2) = '04MARCH 1999' Then insert it into Dobnum else NULL
if (ABCList,3) = 'Passport' Then insert it into Pass1 else NULL
if (ABCList,4) = 'ABCC123' Then insert it into Passnum else NULL
```

But I cant figure out how to move data directly from a string into table.

MAIN CODE:

```
DECLARE @string3 varchar(max) = 'DOB;04MARCH 1999;Passport;ABCC123';
DECLARE @sep3 char(1) = ';'
DECLARE @dot3 char(1) = '.'
DECLARE @tab3 TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Dob1 varchar(max),
    Dobnum varchar(max),
    Pass1 varchar(max),
    Passnum varchar(max)
);

SELECT REVERSE(REPLACE(REVERSE(@string3), @sep3, @dot3)) as ABClist

INSERT into @tab3 (Dob1,Dobnum,Pass1,Passnum)
values
(


);

select * from  @tab3
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you not use `CASE` to achieve what you want?

Something such as

```
INSERT INTO @tab3 (Dob1,Dobnum,Pass1,Passnum)
SELECT 
(
    CASE
        WHEN //Condition == 'DOB1'
           THEN //Whatever
        ELSE NULL
    END
) AS Dob1,
(
    CASE
        WHEN //Condition == '04MARCH 1999'
           THEN //Whatever
        ELSE NULL
    END
) AS Dobnum,
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you this helped but I still have some problem. If I change the string to just @string3 varchar(max) = 'Passport;ABCC123'; then this doesnt work.

Comment: @Tom Well then add a new `CASE` to the `SELECT`. What I have above is just an example